# TensorFlow 2 How to use *args in tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

## Update:

Did a bit more testing and I can't reproduce the behaviour with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.function
def tf_being_unpythonic(an_input, another_input):
    return an_input + another_input

@tf.function
def example(*inputs, other_args = True):
    return tf_being_unpythonic(*inputs)

class TestClass(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.a= a
        self.b = b

    @tf.function
    def call(self, *inps, some_kwarg=False):
        if some_kwarg:
            return self.a(*inps)
        return self.b(*inps)

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.inps = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.hl1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
        self.hl2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    @tf.function
    def call(self,observation):
        x = self.inps(observation)
        x = self.hl1(x)
        x = self.hl2(x)
        return self.out(x)


class Model2(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prein = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()

    @tf.function
    def call(self,b,c):
        x = self.prein([b,c])
        return super().call(x)   

am = Model()
pm = Model2()
test = TestClass(am,pm)

a = np.random.normal(size=(1,2,3))
b = np.random.normal(size=(1,2,4))

test(a,some_kwarg=True)
test(a,b)
```

So it's probably a bug somewhere else.

```
@tf.function
def call(self, *inp, target=False, training=False):
    if not len(inp):
        raise ValueError("Call requires some input")
    if target:
        return self._target_network(*inp, training)
    return self._network(*inp, training)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer flatten is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=1, found ndim=0. Full shape received: []
```

But print(inp) gives:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'inp_0:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32>,)
```

I've since edited and was just uncommited toy code so can't investigate further. Will leave the question here so that everyone who doesn't get this issue won't have something to read.

Comment: Please add a working code exmaple and the full error message. You call function that we do not know and we only see the last line of the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using a `*args` construct is a good practice for a `tf.function`. As you can see, most of the TF functions accepting a variable number of inputs use a tuple.

So, you can rewrite your function signature as:

```py
def call(self, inputs, target=False, training=False)
```

and calling it with:

```py
instance.call((i1, i2, i3), [...])
# instead of instance.call(i1, i2, i3, [...])
```

---

### Edit

By the way, I don't see any error while using `tf.function` with a `*args` construct:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def call(*inp, target=False, training=False):
    if not len(inp):
        raise ValueError("Call requires some input")
    return inp[0]

def main():
    print(call(1))
    print(call(2, 2))
    print(call(3, 3, 3))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

So you should provide us more informations about what you try to do and where the error is.

Comment: I'm aware of this as an option but as this is an abstract class it would be ideal if the trace of the instance.call could have input identifiers for readability rather than a catch all tuple.

Comment: yeah I was just playing around with it. Must be a bug somewhere else :/.
Works fine in eager execution though so it's moderately surprising.

Comment: How do you specify the input_signature when the `inputs` is a list/tuple ?

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a bug that was resolved recently. `*args` and `**kwargs` should work fine.